# Change WebView locale language

Tags: android, webview, localization, locale

I am using WebView to view my application with web interface. In my app one of my settings is my app language.
I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163814/1725836) answer to control the requests with the saved language of my app.

The problem is that `date` or `time` input fields sometimes have different locale than my app. The WebView using the phone language to determine the locale format for these fields.

For example if I use English **(US)** as phone language and set my app to English **(UK)** I still can see the time in `<input type="time">` fields in 12-hours format instead of 24-hours format.

Can I change the language of the WebView manually instead using the default phone language?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope. I wish....

Comment: Then please check my proposal https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4523 I'm sure it will help us maybe you can give your votes too.

Comment: Thanks! Actually this is a good idea. I will vote!